# How can I keep a python script on a remote server running after closing out of SSH?

Tags: python, ssh, console

I've coded a stock trading bot in Python3. I have it hosted on a server (Ubuntu 18.10) that I use iTerm to SSH into. Wondering how to keep the script actively running so that when I exit out of my session it won't kill the active process.

Basically, I want to SSH into my server, start the script then close out and come back into it when the days over to stop the process.

Comment: I'd take a look at [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux), but you can also look into running your script as a daemon

Comment: also here's a good question/answer on AskUbuntu about [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use screen

```
sudo apt-get install screen

screen 

./run-my-script

Ctrl-A then D to get out of your screen
```

From there you will be able to close out your ssh terminal.  Come back later and run

```
screen -ls

screen -r $screen_running
```

The screen running is usually the first 5 digits you see after you've listed all the screens.  You can see if you're script is still running or if you've added logging you can see where in the process you are.

Comment: Thanks! Im gonna try this an tmux

Answer (score 5):

You could use [nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) and add `&` at the end of your command to safely exit you session without killing original process. For example if your script name is `script.py`:

`nohup python3 script.py &`

Normally, when running a command using `&` and exiting the shell afterwards, the shell will terminate the sub-command with the hangup signal (`kill -SIGHUP <pid>`). This can be prevented using `nohup`, as it catches the signal and ignores it so that it never reaches the actual application.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tmux` is a good option. Alternatively you could run the command with an `&` at the end which lets it run in the background.

https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 0):

I came here for finding `nohup python3 script.py &`

Right solution for this thread is `screen` OR `tmux`. :)